# Acessar website em rede local através do meu celular Android

Tags: php, mysql

Fiz um site em PHP e MySQL responsivo e gostaria de acessá-lo no meu celular Android pelo localhost, sei que tenho que colocar meu IP no *browser* do celular mas quando mando acessar ele aparece o seguinte erro:

> Forbidden You don't have permission to access/ on this server.

Comment: Qual o webserver que você está usando?

Comment: Assumindo que você está usando Apache, coloque `Allow from all` em um arquivo `.htaccess` na raiz do site que você está testando. A instrução padrão para o localhost no Apache é aceitar conexões somente do IP 127.0.0.1, ou seja, o próprio computador que o hospeda, e seu celular vai ter um IP diferente na hora da conexão.

Comment: Se você estiver usando algum tipo de roteador (da net ou outra operadora) e o IP real não estiver dentro do seu computador, você precisará redirecionar a porta 80 no seu roteador pro seu computador.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de tentar o que funcionou para todos nas experências pesquisadas, sem sucesso, descobri que meu problema estava no bloqueio pelo firewall do antivirus.

Compartilho um resumo de como consegui acessar o localhost com XAMPP pelo celular android. Isso funcionou no celular tanto para acesso do localhost pelo browser Chrome quanto para leitura de um banco de dados mysql no meu APP.

Processo completo:

1. Liberar o Apache HTTP no firewall do windows ou do seu antivirus, conforme o caso. ### ESSE É O PONTO QUE MUITA GENTE SE ESQUECE ##. No meu caso, o firewall está controlado pelo antivirus McAfee.
   [image: Liberando o Apache HTTP Server no firewall do antivirus]
2. Ativar ou reiniciar o Apache no XAMPP.
3. O celular deve estar na mesma rede wi-fi em que está o XAMPP ativado.
4. Obter o IPv4 do PC. No Windows > prompt de comando (cmd) > ipconfig.
   [image: Localizando o IPv4 do PC]
5. Para testar a conexão, abrir o navegador no celular e digitar o IPv4.
   [image: Localhost acessado pelo browser do celular]
6. No seu app, incluir este IPv4 conforme o caso.

É isso.

Answer (score 10):

## WAMP Server

Se você usar o [WAMP Server](http://www.wampserver.com/en/), é bem simples.

- Clique no ícone do WAMP na área de notificações do Windows e clique em "Colocar online":

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Descubra o IP do seu computador na sua rede. Para isso, abra o prompt de comandos e digite `ipconfig`. Copie o IP que estiver logo após "Endereço IPv4":

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Digite o IP do seu computador no navegador do seu celular e voilà. Talvez seja necessário confirmar a solicitação no firewall do seu computador:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

## XAMPP

No XAMPP, edite o arquivo `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf`

Transforme isso:

```
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
    Require local
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

Nisso:

```
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
    #Require local
    #ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

Então restarte o Apache pelo XAMPP Control Panel. E teste no celular usando o IP do computador, como mostrado no tutorial para o WAMP.

Comment: Muito bom! bem simples!

Answer (score 3):

Ja me deparei com esse erro, e utilizava o Apache, e solucionei da seguinte forma:

Na pasta

> bin\apache\apache.versão.x\conf\

abra o arquivo

> httpd.conf

procure a linha:

```
listen 80
```

E mude ela para:

```
listen 0.0.0.0:80
```

Funcinou para mim, espero que funcione para você.

(destaquei o texto dessa forma porque o negrito não tava funcionando para mim)

Comment: **Se for empresa**, vou recomendar colocar o IP da máquina que serve de host. **Caso contrário**, uma abordagem `listen *:80` seria *'universal'*

Answer (score 2):

Para configurar usando linux:

1-abra o terminal

2-use o comando hostname -I

3-copie o seu ip no seu celular, no meu caso: 10.0.0.10:8080.(8080 é a porta que será colocada no servidor, ficando ao seu criterio).

4-suba o servidor com na sua pasta com o comando php -S 0.0.0.0:8080

**esse comando funciona apenas na versão superior ou igual a 5.4+**

Answer (score -1):

Precisa utilizar apenas 2 recursos no browser do seu celular:

1. Seu IP Gateway (Não é o IP local)##
2. Sua porta Apache##

---

#### Para Windows:

- Clique no botão do Menu iniciar e acesse o campo de busca do Windows. Ali, digite o caminho “CMD” para acessar o Prompt de comando.
- No Prompt digite `ipconfig` e tecle Enter.
- Receberá como retorno uma lista com várias informações, entre elas o seu “Gateway Padrão”.
- Vá no seu AMP e copie a porta Apache que está em uso (recomenda-se 8888)
- No browser do seu celular digite seu IP Gateway + sua porta. Exemplo: `192.148.16.236:8888`
- Serão listados todos os diretórios de localhost.

  ---

#### Para Mac:

- Abra as "Preferências do Sistema".
- Clique em Redes e seleciona a rede da conexão vigente.
- Copie o IP que aparece no canto superior direito, este é seu Gateway.
- Vá no seu AMP e copie a porta Apache que está em uso (recomenda-se 8888)
- No browser do seu celular digite seu IP Gateway + sua porta. Exemplo: `192.148.16.236:8888`
- Serão listados todos os diretórios de localhost.