# Problemas de acesso no XAMPP

Tags: html5, xampp

estou tentando abrir uma imagem .png via url pelo localhost e a seguinte mensagem aparece:

[image: Imagem de erro.]

Comment: Dá uma olhada nessa resposta (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/46438/622) na parte que fala sobre o XAMPP. É só editar o arquivo `httpd-xampp.conf`.